# Importar csv com pandas. Valores da coluna com ponto e vírgula. O que fazer?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Estou importando arquivos csv com o pandas para fazer uma limpeza nos dados.
E estou encontrando um problema.
Alguns valores tem ';' .

Por exemplo: df[0][1] = "RUA A ; "

Importo o csv através de:
df = pd.read_csv('GUAXUPE.csv', header = None, sep = ',', encoding = 'utf-8')

E apesar de ter colocado o separador como a vírgula, o pandas reconhece o ' ; ' como um separador e acrescenta um campo aonde não devia, desregulando parte da tabela.

Já pesquisei na internet, li a parte da documentação do pandas que fala do read_csv() e não encontrei resposta. Alguém tem uma idéia ?

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de contornar é unir a coluna com a informação à esquerda do ";" com a coluna contendo a informação à direita do ";".
Ficaria algo assim:

```
df['dados_esquerda']+=";"+df['dados_direita']
```

Caso não queria nomear as colunas, acredito que esse poderia ser feito assim:

```
df.loc[:,1]+=";"+df.loc[:,2]
```

No exemplo acima, assumi que a segunda coluna contenha os dados à esquerda do ";" e a terceira coluna os dados à direita do ";".

Posteriormente, você pode apagar a coluna indesejada com o comando del:

```
del df[2] #ou del df['dados_direita']
```

Comment: Mas o problema é que é um dataframe gigantesco. Na verdade escrevi um script para tratar vários arquivos csv. importei os dados de cnpj , cnae , do site da receita federal ; e estou tratando-os.  E para fazer isso , que você sugeriu , eu precisaria saber exatamente quais linhas e quais colunas, o problema acontece.

Comment: O problema é na hora da importação do CSV  pelo panda. quando passo o read_csv() ele reconhece o ponto e virgula , mesmo entre aspas , como um separador.

Comment: Eu cheguei a importar usando o módulo csv do python , e depois transformando  o dicionario em um dataframe. Ficou melhor . Mas ainda gera um problema de formatação das colunas...

Comment: Eu tive o mesmo problema quando gerei um dicionário com todas as CNAES e seus significados, e fiz a substituições da mesma na coluna CNAE .   O dicionário tinha espaçamento com o TAB . E quando fazia a substituição na coluna, o pandas lia o TAB como um separador . Isso foi fácil de resolver. Usei o VScode com crl shift seta pra baixo e eliminei todos espaçamentos tab de uma vez.

Comment: Na verdade precisaria saber somente em quais colunas o problema acontece.
Você poderia colar uma linha do csv aqui para eu poder entender melhor como ele é?

Comment: "00317713000183","1","WANDERLEIA SABBAG DUARTE","PRIVILEGIUS MULTI-MARCAS","04","20190124","63","","","","2135","19941129","4781400","AVENIDA","CONDE RIBEIRO DO VALLE","1243","LETRA: A;","IRMAOS RICCIARDI","37800000","MG","4573","GUAXUPE","35","35514071","","","","","ASSESCON.RONI@VELOXMAIL.COM.BR","50","0.0","01","6","20070701","20121231","N","",""
"00317713000183","1","WANDERLEIA SABBAG DUARTE","PRIVILEGIUS MULTI-MARCAS","04","20190124","63","","","","2135","19941129","4781400","AVENIDA","CONDE RIBEIRO DO VALLE","1243","LETRA: A;","IRMAOS RICCIARDI","37800000","MG","4573"

Comment: Essa é uma das linhas de um dos csv  que dá problema . Veja que um dos valores é "LETRA:A;"

Comment: Mas não são todos valores da coluna que isso acontece. Nesse csv tem umas 10 linhas  apenas que tem um valor com ponto e virgula,entre as 25000 .

Comment: É um csv para cada município do Brasil . No total , 26 GB.

Comment: Pelo visto, todos os campos possuem aspas duplas no início e no final do valor.
Nesse caso, faça um teste usando como separador "," aos invés da vírgula simples. Se não funcionar, tente usar sep='["]*,["]*'
Outra alternativa é importar o csv usando nova linha como separador. Aí na linha gigante que será criada, rodar um script para remover os ";". Salvar o CSV novamente e então reimportar.

Comment: Tentei, e não deu certo. O pandas insiste em reconhecer o ponto e vírgula como um separador, mesmo recebendo a vírgula ou qualquer outro elemento como separador. Ele reconhece também o espaçamento TAB como um separador. Tive um problema no passado com ele. Mas esse foi fácil de resolver. Era um dicionário com todos códigos CNAES e seu significado. Cortei todos espaçamentos de uma vez.

Answer (score 0):

No comando engine acrescente o parametro engine, ficaria assim:

```
df = pd.read_csv('GUAXUPE.csv', header = None, sep = ',', encoding = 'utf-8',engine='c')
```

Na documentação do read_csv diz que a engine do Python reconhece separadores automaticamente, a engine do C não. Acredito que pode uncionar.

segue a doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Eu tentei. Não deu certo. Continua reconhecendo o ponto e vírgula como separador.

Comment: Estou tentando usar o módulo CSV do python também.  A função que converte o csv para um dicionário acaba excluindo duas colunas onde aparecem esses caracteres que estão interferindo na formação da tabela.  De um lado, resolve , mas de outro não,pois preciso dessas informações,

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o mistério!
O problema não era no pandas. Mas sim a maneira que estava fazendo a supervisão das tabelas geradas. Quando abria o arquivo .csv no libre office, o programa pedia inicialmente pra escolher quais caracteres seriam considerados como separador. E automaticamente, o ponto e vírgula estava selecionado.
Fiz a supervisão das tabelas pelo jupyter notebook, e está tudo certo !